# can you re-write Google to say what you want it to, using F12 in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer

I was in IE9 and my friend said that you can change websites to make them say what you want them to using the <kbd>F12</kbd> command
 . Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

With the developer tools, you can't modify the content on the web server, you can only modify the DOM. The DOM is the browser's way of representing the page.